# Diary App which supports Tags with values

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I am looking for a diary app, which supports **tags with values**. Which means I can define custom tags, and with each entry I can add tags and define values for it. 
Example:

- 01/01/2013 had a great party today, mood:5, health:7, moneySpent:152
- 02/01/2013 met Tina today, went to the pool, mood:7, success:3

It should provide some line charts to see how the values go up and down.

I couldn't find it using my search terms, maybe you know how to call this feature, or know an app implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

A great diary app is Momento. Supports tags and has a great interface:
http://www.momentoapp.com/